# PXE booting is failing

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm

So PXE booting is failing for some reason. We have three separate networks, and it works on one network, but not for another. We're using SCCM. Our firewall is fine. Open or diabled TFTP is refused but the port is open and the service is running. We've rebooted the server and tried to TFTP directly but no dice. DHCP gets the option properly. In SCCM the settings are copied exactly from the working network.

The error on the machines when trying to PXE boot right now is No boot filename received

Comment: Use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to analyze the network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

check your ip helper/ dhcp relay agent configuration in the networks that are not working.

Answer (score 1):

`No boot filename received`  does not mean a TFTP error. In fact it tells you the DHCP service did not provide the required PXE parameters. In this case the `filepath/name of the NBP` (Network Boot Program).

If the TFTP service also fails on a different network please consider TFTP is a protocol that begins on port `69` but the data transfer is later moved to a randomly selected port. If those ports are closed you won't ever get a good TFTP transfer.